# returning new set from jquery's .wrap()

Tags: jquery

jQuery's [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes.

What is the most elegant way to return the original set of elements + the wrapped elements instead?

Comment: Isn't the original set of elements the same thing as the "wrapped elements"? Or are you talking about getting a collection that is instead the elements created by wrap()?

Comment: Sorry, I've re-worded my question. I'm looking to return the original set + the wrapped elements themselves so that I continue chaining from that point on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you'll need [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [`andSelf()`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/).

- `parent()` will retrieve the parent for each element in the collection.
- `andSelf()` will add the former collection to the new collection.

`$("div.elements-to-wrap").wrap('<div class="wrapper" />').parent().andSelf();`

Now, you have a new collection that contains both `div.elements-to-wrap` and all the `div.wrapper` that wrap the former elements.